# Responsive JavaScript management

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design

I am looking to create a responsive website. I want certain JavaScript, i.e. navigation jquery, to run only on the mobile version, and another navigation jquery to run on the desktop version for the same element. I came across RespondJS (http://responsejs.com/) and Media Check (https://github.com/sparkbox/mediaCheck). I am not sure if they are the right solution, can someone give me a suggestion?

I am looking for something like:

```
<script>

(some code to check if desktop) {
   $(".navigation").runDesktopNavstyle();
   $(".slideshow").runDesktopSlideshow();
}

(some code to check if tablet) {
   $(".navigation").runTabletNavstyle();
   $(".slideshow").runTabletSlideshow();
}

(some code to check if mobile) {
   $(".navigation").runMobileNavstyle();
   $(".slideshow").runMobileSlideshow();
}

</script>
```

Comment: you don't need javascript to go responsive as of these days ;) see this article: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: Sorry, I meant like I want to use a different javascript applied for the navigation while its viewed on the desktop, and totally another one applied while on the mobile or tablet.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest option would be to wrap your conditional code in something like this:

```
if( window.innerWidth < 640) { ... } // max-width:640px
if( window.innerHeight > 800) { ... } // min-height:800px
if( window.innerWidth < window.innerHeight) { ... } // orientation:portrait
```

Things like that. Note however that it should only be wrapped around the contents of functions, so you can still define them. For exampple:

```
$("#mynav").hover(function() {
    if( window.innerWidth < 640) { /* do stuff */ }
},...);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend supplying different forms of JavaScript up depending on whether you're on a phone or desktop etc, it can become a maintenance nightmare and not really what responsive is about, you might as well have a separate site for mobile in that case.

However, using Bootstrap you could apply the responsive classes to your elements then using jQuery you can look for and select on those classes. This means you're providing the same JavaScript files up but making them a little more intelligent when dealing with the elements they need to, for example:

```
<div class="visible-phone">
</div>

<div class="visible-desktop">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$('.visible-phone').length > 0) {
   // Do phone stuff
}

$('.visible-desktop').length > 0) {
   // Do desktop stuff
}

</script>
```

Very rough, but you get the idea.